# Use Taggit-Selectize in Django to autocomplete the tags in User Form outside the Admin

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, selectize.js, django-taggit

I am using this https://github.com/chhantyal/taggit-selectize which uses django-taggit and selectize.js to add autocompletion of tags in my blog app. 
I have followed the instructions in the readme file and it works fine in admin.

But when I am trying to use it in User form , it is not working. I have used this https://github.com/chhantyal/taggit-selectize/issues/17 to customize my form and have tried using the js and css file almost everywhere in my HTML template as suggested in the above post. But I am not able to get it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/taggit_selectize/js/selectize.js"></script>

<link href="/static/taggit_selectize/css/selectize.django.css" type="text/css" media="all" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

PS. I am also using Martor Django Editor which uses semantic.js (Mentioning it because it had conflict with few of my JS and bootstrap stuff.)

Comment: Any js errors in your browser console? Any python errors reported?

Comment: No. No errors in console or python.

Comment: Well, what is shown in your django runserver console? (where you ran python manage.py runserver). That will reveal if there is successful communication between front and backend.

Comment: It is showing all the loaded css and js. Too big for me to copy it here. But interestingly It is showing 
"GET /static/taggit_selectize/css/selectize.django.css HTTP/1.1" 304 0
but not the selectize js.

Comment: Add the selectize js to top of your page and see if that fixes things.

Comment: See my first comment here https://github.com/chhantyal/taggit-selectize/issues/16

Comment: "{% static '/taggit_selectize/js/selectize.js' %}"> Using this instead of "/static/taggit_selectize/js/selectize.js' %}"> has helped . But now I have some questions, does it work in the form exaclty it does in the admin ? Because for me it is not working in the same way, it is showing me a long list of suggestions, adding the duplicates (unlike admin) and not adding the tag on tab.

Comment: no thank-you for helping you solve this problem? I don't see why I should continue to help.

Comment: Man, I am thankful to you but since I have preceding questions I had reserved it for the end.